# How do i get the while true loop to keep running when anything other than (P,p,d,d) is entered. Current it just repeats if (P,p,d,d)

Tags: python

How do i get the while true loop to keep running when anything other than (P,p,d,d) is entered. Current it only repeats if (P,p,d,d) is entered. If i enter otherwise it prints "Invalid" and moves on to the next loop.

```
while True:
    print("How did you acquire the flat ")
    source = input("(Purchased (P) || Produced (D) ) : ")
    if ((source != 'P') and (source != 'p') and (source != 'd') and (source != 'D')):
        print("\n Invalid Code\n")
        break;
  
 
while True:
    print("\nPlease Select the type of egg ")
    type = input("\n (W)et \n (B)ig \n (F)ree  \n (O)ld  : ")
    if (type != 'W' and type != 'B' and type != 'F' and type != 'O' and type != 'w' and type != 'b' and type != 'f' and type != 'o'):
        print("\n Invalid Code\n")
        break;
```

Comment: You are exiting the loop when the input is not one of `['P', 'p', 'D', 'd']`, when you should instead be continuing the loop in that case, and only exiting if the input **is** one of `['P', 'p', 'D', 'd']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The while loop should only break if the input is a valid code, and continue (after printing the error message) otherwise. You can also simplify your if statement conditions WLOG.

```
while True:
    print("How did you acquire the flat ")
    source = input("(Purchased (P) || Produced (D) ) : ")
    if source.lower() in ['p', 'd']:
        break

    print("\n Invalid Code\n")

   
while True:
    print("\nPlease Select the type of egg ")
    type = input("\n (W)et \n (B)ig \n (F)ree  \n (O)ld  : ")
    if type.lower() in ['w', 'b', 'f', 'o']:
        break

    print("\n Invalid Code\n")
```

Lastly, you should avoid using names from the built-in namespace as variable names (`type` is a built-in function).